# What is the Catholic Church's position on recreational marijuana use?

Tags: catholicism, sin, drugs

Several US states have passed voter initiatives to allow recreational marijuana use for adults.  What is the Catholic Church’s official position on this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under **Respect for health** in [Catechism of the Catholic Church, 2291](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s2c2a5.htm#2291) the Church teaches

> The *use of drugs* inflicts very grave damage on human health and
>   life. Their use, except on strictly therapeutic grounds, is a grave
>   offense. Clandestine production of and trafficking in drugs are
>   scandalous practices. They constitute direct co-operation in evil,
>   since they encourage people to practices gravely contrary to the moral
>   law.

Thus the recreational use marijuana, considered a drug, would not be permissible.

*And from the Vatican?*

> Other churches take more of a hard-line approach to marijuana. The
>   Catholic Church says that drugs "constitute direct co-operation in
>   evil" and does not seem to make exceptions for marijuana. The Vatican
>   has condemned legalizing "soft drugs" like marijuana, and its
>   newspaper, *L'Osservatore Romano*, recently scolded Italian lawmakers
>   for liberalizing pot-possession laws. - *Source:* [What Would Jesus
>   Smoke? By Torie Bosch | Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2007/03/what_would_jesus_smoke.html).

Please see also:

- [A real cure and prevention | On the campaigns to legalize drugs | *L'Osservatore Romano*, June 9, 2011](http://www.osservatoreromano.va/en/news/a-real-cure-and-prevention).

> In this health emergency, the attempt to muddy the waters by
>   classifying as a drug everything from wine to LSD is pathetic. So is
>   the attempt to say that one need only know how to take them in
>   moderation, without remembering that wine is a food nutrient and
>   tobacco does not make you lose your head, but marijuana does. We are
>   the first to be scandalized by the early consumption of tobacco and
>   alcohol by young people and we ask for strong restrictions for youth
>   and a clear campaign to dissuade binge drinking or the use of
>   nicotine, but this does not mean that one needs to add a third
>   disaster to the first two, especially at a time when the first two are
>   showing signs of success.

- And the first link below where Pope Francis is quoted as condemning the legalization of marijuana.

---

Please see also:

- [Pope Francis condemns legalization of marijuana | Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS569US569&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pope%20condemns%20legalization%20of%20marijuana).
- [AMERICA/URUGUAY - The legalization of marijuana will destroy family](http://www.news.va/en/news/americauruguay-the-legalization-of-marijuana-will-).
- [To Puff or Not to Puff, by NISSA LAPOINT | NCR](http://www.ncregister.com/daily-news/to-puff-or-not-to-puff/).